# iframe responsive in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'd like to embed some d3.js chart in a WordPress page.
I choose not to use any plugin but load .html file in media e embed them in an iframe.
I cannot make them responsive and I tried most of the common tricks suggested.
The code works fine outside wordpress: if I view the html file I'm trying to embed on a browser stand alone, its content is actually responsive. In WP it isn't.
This is the code in the iframe

```
<div class="responsive-embed-container">
<iframe 
width="100%" height="100%"
src="https://mysite/uploads/2020/09/index.html" 
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true"
scrolling="no">
</iframe>
</div>
```

This is the relative css

```
.responsive-embed-container {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:56.25%;
    height:0;
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
.responsive-embed-container iframe, .responsive-embed-container object, .responsive-embed-container embed {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
  border: 0px;
}
```

Any clues? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You say it works when not used inside of your WordPress page - however, all you gave us was the iFrame code that works. We have no way of testing this since we do not have access to your WP code. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This is quite frankly not a good way to do this. First and foremost introducing this content in iframe no matter the additional code will not result in a robust implementation for responsive design. Different devices will treat each view space as separate and apply a different way to calculate the size. Secondly, code from within an iframe depending on the implementation might affect other elements on the site and vice versa which brings additional uncertainty especially when implementing graphs and visualizations. If you wish and agree I can post here on how to do it directly via Wordpress.